# Error with REFERENCING mariadb syntax

Tags: triggers, mariadb

```
CREATE TRIGGER printMoneyUSA
    AFTER UPDATE ON USA
    REFERENCING
        OLD ROW AS old
        NEW ROW AS new

    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF old.SUPPLY_OF_CURRENCY = 0 THEN
        SET new.SUPPLY_OF_CURRENCY = 30000000000;
    END IF;
END;//
```

Hello, I keep getting a syntax error for the 'REFERENCING' syntax that says:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
>
> ```
> 'REFERENCING
>     OLD ROW AS old
>     NEW ROW AS new
>
>  FOR EACH ROW BEGI' at line 3.
> ```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on mariadb's documentation on [create trigger](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-trigger/), mariadb does not have the referencing clause:

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE]
    [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER | role | CURRENT_ROLE }]
    TRIGGER [IF NOT EXISTS] trigger_name trigger_time trigger_event
    ON tbl_name FOR EACH ROW
   [{ FOLLOWS | PRECEDES } other_trigger_name ]
   trigger_stmt
```

You have to remove the referencing clause and simply use `OLD` / `NEW` to reference the versions of the record.

Comment: Okay, I tried that, but I'm still getting a syntax error somewhere:

Comment: DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS printMoneyUSA //
CREATE TRIGGER printMoneyUSA
    BEFORE UPDATE OF SUPPLY_OF_CURRENCY ON USA

    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF OLD.SUPPLY_OF_CURRENCY == 0 THEN
            SET NEW.SUPPLY_OF_CURRENCY = 30000000000;
        END IF;
    END //
DELIMITER;

Comment: There is no `==`, only `=`. But if you have a new question, pls ask it as a new question in its own post, not in comment.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB and MySQL don't have a `REFERENCING` clause.  `OLD` automatically refers to the "old" row.  Similarly for `NEW`.